# Google in app purchase refund api using php

Tags: php, in-app-billing, in-app

Is there any api(Rest) or procedure to refund Google In app product price? Which is provided from Google Play store side. 
I am looking for the solution for same, but not got yet. Anybody please guide / suggest me about this. 
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for [Administering In-App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-refunds), it states this for managed products:

> Important: You cannot use the API to issue refunds or cancel In-app Billing transactions. You must do this manually through your Google payments merchant account. However, you can use the API to retrieve order information.

Refunds for in-app purchases must be directed to the app developer. You can then process the refund through your Google payments merchant account.

You can however, use the [API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) to [refund and revoke subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#refunds),

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See how to authorized first here: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/orders/refund

[image]